# Angular select emit option with object

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app, I have a `<select>` with a list of `<option>`s whose values are bound to objects.

I'm trying to get the last value selected using:

```
<select (change)="onSelect($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let option of myOptions;" [ngValue]="option"> {{ option.name }} </option>
</select>
```

```
onSelect(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

So my options are bound to objects (`myOptions` is an array of objects).

This works fine and the `{{ option.name }}` (that is a string) is correctly displayed.

The problem is that the `event.target.value` in my `onSelect` will be a string like `"1: Object"`, `"2: Object"`, etc...

If I use `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]` the problem would be slightly different and the `event.target.value` would this time be the `"[object Object]"` string.

How can I get the real selected object `option` when emitting the `(change)` event?

Comment: minimal repro on stackblitz?

Comment: by the way, is it the only information you need or is this part of a bigger form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't assign to value an object, it should be a string value. Take a look at this post [Can the select option value be of different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901125/can-the-select-option-value-be-of-different-types).

One option could be using an index to the array,

```
<select (change)="onSelect($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let option of myOptions; index as i;" [value]="i"> {{ option.name }} </option>
</select>
```

Or if you have an id in your option,

```
<select (change)="onSelect($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let option of myOptions" [value]="option.id"> {{ option.name }} </option>
</select>
```

You have a number of options to choose.

Answer (score 0):

tried using below code

in html use ngModelChange instead of change event

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" name="data">
      <option *ngFor="let currentData of allData" [ngValue]="currentData"> {{currentData.name}}</option>
</select>
```

in ts

```
allData = [{ name: "data1", id: 1 }, { name: "data2", id: 2 }];
dataChanged(event) {
    console.log(event); // here you will able to see whole object in console
  }
```

thanks

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi i have got ans from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136548/angular-4-using-objects-for-option-values-in-a-select-list/45137528 link will help you for more